# Train / Test split % for Object Detection - what's the current recommendation?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

Using the Tensorflow Object Detection API, what's the current recommendation / best practice around the train / test split percentage for labeled examples? I've seen a lot of conflicting info, anywhere from 70/30 to 95/5. Any recent real world experience is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional advice is ~70-75% training and the rest test data. More recent articles indeed suggest a different split. I read 95/2.5/2.5 (train / test / dev for hyperparameter tuning) a lot these days.

I guess your optimal split depends on the amount of available data and the bias/variance characteristics. Poor performance on training data may be caused by underfitting and need more training data. If your model is fitting well or even overfitting, you should be able to allocate some of the training data away to test data.

If you're stuck in the middle, you may also consider cross validation as a computationally expensive but data friendly option.

Comment: could you please tell what the source of "more recent articles" is?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the dataset as Andrew Ng suggests:
(train/ dev or Val /test)

```
If the size of the dataset is 100 to 10K ~ 60/20/20
If the size of the dataset is 1M to INF ==> 98/1/1 or 99.5/0.25/0.25
```

Note that these are not fixed and just suggestions.

The goal of the test set mentioned here is to give you an unbiased performance measurement of your work. In some works, it is OK not to have only two sets set (then they will call it train/test, though test set here is actually working as dev set ratio can be 70/30 )